# What is the path of mapping file on Crashlytics server once crashlytics plugin automatically upload mapping file to crashlytics server?

Tags: proguard, crashlytics

I have added following code inside proguard-rules.pro for producing redable crash report once proguard enabled in my project.

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable        # Keep file names and line numbers.
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception  # Optional: Keep custom exceptions.
```

I haven't add mappingsFileUploadEnabled in build.gradle. So that means as per crashlytics documentation,  plugin will automatically upload mapping file.

When i build the project my mapping file generated under build->outputs->mapping

Anyone please tell me crashlytics plugin on which location uploading this mapping file automatically ? Can i view this file on crashlytics portal once plugin uploaded to mapping file ?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment is not possible to see the uploaded mapping files in the Crashlytics dashboard.

After building the app, you would need to cause a [test crash](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android) and see if the code has been deobfuscated. If it is, then that means the mapping file got uploaded correctly.

If it doesn't, you could try running the gradle task that upload the mapping file and see if there are errors. for this you can use this command:

```
./gradlew app:uploadCrashlyticSymbolFileDebug --console=plain --debug | grep "com.google.firebase.crashlytics"
```

Comment: 1) which buildVariant mapping file will get upload using above command.                       2) Is there any crashlytics official documentation where mentioned not possible to see the uploaded mapping files

Comment: 1) This name "uploadCrashlyticSymbolFile" should have variants depending on the build variant. For release it should be "uploadCrashlyticSymbolFileRelease". 2) AFAIK there isn't.